# which databases can be used better for pyqt application

Tags: python, database, pyqt

i want to create application in windows. i need to use databases which would be preferable best for pyqt application

like
sqlalchemy
mysql
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use SQLite every time unless performance became an *obvious* big problem.

- It comes with Python
- You don't need to worry about installing it on a target machine or having an existing installation which might clash (including a potential port clash - SQLite doesn't use a port)
- It's fairly small (doesn't increase the installed size *too* much)

Then, a much less obvious choice that I would very much consider making: adding [Django](http://djangoproject.com/) to the mix. Django's model system could make for much simpler management, depending on the type of data you're working with. Also, in the case where I've considered it (I just haven't got to that stage of development yet) it means I can reuse the models I've got on the server and a good bit of code from there too.

Obviously in this case you could need to be careful about what you expose; business-critical processing stuff that you don't want to share, potential security holes in server code which you've helpfully provided the code for, etc.

Answer (score 1):

SQlite is fine for a single user.

If you are going over a network to talk to a central database, then you need a database woith a decent Python lirary.

Take a serious look at MySQL if you need/want SQL.

Otherwise, there is CouchDB in the Not SQL camp, which is great if you are storing documents, and can express searches as Map/reduce functions. Poor for adhoc queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a relational database I'd recommend you to use SQLAlchemy, as you then get a choice as well as an ORM. Bu default go with SQLite, as per other recommendations here.

If you don't need a relational database, take a look at ZODB. It's an awesome Python-only object-oriented database.

Answer (score 0):

i guess its totally upto you ..but as far as i am concerned i personlly use sqlite, becoz it is easy to use and amazingly simple syntax whereas for MYSQL u can use it for complex apps and has  options for performance tuning. but in end its totally upto u and wt your app requires